# Lasso solution with Rcpp: A self study

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I'm very new to Rcpp. I 'm trying to write a coordinate descent algorithm for lasso in Rcpp as a self study. The code return an error:

```
Mat::init(): requested size is not compatible with column vector layout
```

I also have some problems while writing the code.

1. no matching function for call to 'sign'
2. no matching function for call to 'ifelse'
3. pow(X.col(j),2) : no viable conversion

I write

- `(S1>0)-(S1<0)` for (1) to compute the sign of `S1`,
- a `if(){}else{}` statement for (2) and
- `X.col(j)%X.col(j)` for (3).

Any suggestion, please?

Here is the code.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp; 
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
mat betamat(NumericMatrix Xr, NumericVector yr, NumericVector lambdar, double tol=0.0000001) {
  int N = Xr.nrow(), p = Xr.ncol(), l = lambdar.size();
  mat X(Xr.begin(), N, p, false);
  colvec y(yr.begin(), yr.size(), false);
  vec lambda(lambdar.begin(), lambdar.size(),false);
  colvec ols = solve(X,y);
  mat betas = zeros<mat>(p,l);
  //
  bool converged = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    colvec b = zeros<vec>(p);
    colvec r = y-X*b;
    while(converged == false){
      colvec beta_old = betas;
      for(int j = 0; j < p; ++j){
      r = r + X.col(j)*b(j);
      double xr = dot(X.col(j),r);
      double S1 = xr/N;
      double xx = sum(X.col(j)%X.col(j))/N;   
      b(j) =((S1>0)-(S1<0))*(abs(S1)-lambda(i))/xx;
      if(b(j)>0){
        b(j)=b(j);
      }else{
        b(j)=0;
      }
      r = r - X.col(j)*b(j);
      }
      converged = (sum(abs(betas - beta_old)) < tol);
    }
    betas.col(i) = b;
  }
  return betas;
}
```

In `R`, I'm calling this with

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("filename.cpp")

set.seed(1)
X <- matrix(rnorm(100*3),100)
y <- rnorm(100)
coefficients <- betamat(X,y,seq(0,1,0.0005))
```

Comment: How are you calling the code?

Comment: @coatless calling with `sourceCpp("filename.cpp")`. Then `coefficients = betamat(X,y,seq(0,1,0.05))`  in `R`. Here `X` is a matrix, `y` is a vector.

Comment: I attached the `R` code, that I used.

Comment: Start with one third of the code size and get the warnings out of the way, one by one. Then add your code back in, line by line.  "There is Free Lunch (TM)." Debugging work too.

Comment: Ooops. Missed the required *no* as "There is (of course) No Free Lunch (TM)".

Comment: A few comments: `ols` is calculated but never used. Assigning `mat betas` to `colvec beta_old` is probably the source of the error. You can use `arma` data types directly as function arguments. Do you have a source for this particular version of the LASSO?

Comment: @Ralf Stubner You are right, thanks. By the way, the problem about `sign` and `ifelse` are still continue. The code similar to the one above can be found  [here](https://github.com/fditraglia/lasso-shooting/blob/master/lasso_shooting.R) as an `R` code,

Comment: Armadillo does support `sign`, c.f. http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#misc_fns. For `ifelse` you will have to use a loop or an STL algorithm. BTW, did you see the [C++ version](https://github.com/fditraglia/lasso-shooting/blob/master/lasso_shooting.cpp) parallel to the cited R code?

Comment: No, I did not. Thank you for the information.